# drop down menu first level is not changing the color

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

In my navigation bar, I've drop down menu. Problem is when i hover on menu drop down is working fine, but when drop down menu appears the menu item on which we hover loose the color
here is the link
http://www.etekstudio.org/demo/biodiag/

here is the screenshot
http://prntscr.com/37rfq1

Comment: add jsfiddle demo to your question pls

Comment: I like your social media icon animations, where did you get them from?

Comment: @Samira KhorshidiI 've add the website link

Answer (score 0):

Simply add declaration of color (red for example) that you want with the following rule

```
.scndryMenu > li:hover > a 
{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: when mouse leave color turns into the orignal color,

Comment: Did you change something on he website? Currently, every sub-menu links becomes red....

Comment: yes, I'm trying, i jst want on hover parent li should be in red on mouse hover or weather cursor on dropdown menu.

Comment: Please, doing it... make impossible our tries to help you.... if you could revert to original situation.... I'll try to asjust my proposed solution...

Comment: sure, you can check now

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to add a class name to the parent `li` on hover over the dropdown menu item and then apply the desired color for the main-menu item targeting the parent li.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/LYxLF/)

In the demo when you hover over a sub menu item, it adds the class name 'active' to all its parent `li` items and then add the below style the hover state color as below and it will be applied to both the main and sub-menu items.

```
li.active > a{
    color:red;
}
```